# Lectura de archivo de texto en C

Tags: c, fopen

Actualmente estoy estudiando acerca de la lectura de entrada y salidas por archivos de texto(.txt) en C y estaba resolviendo un problema que decía lo siguiente:
**Utilizar la función fopen(), para determinar si existe un archivo de texto(.txt) o no.** Y bueno lo resolví, sin embargo, hice 3 soluciones para el mismo problema, pero las otras dos a la hora de compilar la solucion #2 y #3 me dice "El archivo a buscar NO EXISTE", cosa que esta mal. Así que, si alguien que me pudiera explicar porfavor, porque de mis posibles 3 soluciones solamente la solución #1 a la hora de compilar el programa me dice que "El archivo a buscar SI EXISTE"(es decir, es LA CORRECTA), se los agradecería mucho.

SOLUCION #1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *fp;

int main(){
    
    if((fp==fopen("programa1.txt", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("El archivo NO EXISTE...\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("El archivo SI EXISTE...\n");
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

SOLUCION #2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *fp;

int main(){
    
    fp = fopen("programa1.txt", "r");
    
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("El archivo NO EXISTE...\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("El archivo SI EXISTE...\n");
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

SOLUCION #3:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *fp;

int main(){
    
    char direccion[] = "C:\\Users\reus\Desktop\programas\\programa1.txt";
        
    fp = fopen(direccion, "r");
    
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("El archivo NO EXISTE...\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("El archivo SI EXISTE...\n");
        printf("Su direccion es: %s\n", direccion);
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

NOTA: Guarde el archivo de texto(.txt), y dicho programa en la misma carpeta.

Comment: La primera solución está mal. Estás comparando el valor devuelto por `fopen` con el contenido que tenga `fp` (no tiene sentido). Cuando en realidad debería ser así: `if((fp=fopen("programa1.txt", "r")) ==NULL)`. Por cierto, la solución 2 y 3 están bien. `fopen` devolverá `NULL` si especificaste mal la ruta del archivo, así que debes verificar eso.

Comment: Tienes razón, agregue de más un "=" entre fp y fopen.

Comment: Revisare de nuevo la ruta de mi archivo. Y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en usar "==" en lugar de "=" para asignación en

```
if ( (fp==fopen("programa1.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
```

Aqui lo que haces es llamar a `fopen`, que retorna `NULL` al no encontrar el archivo. La variable `fp` también es `NULL`, asi que la comparación por igual resulta cierta.

La forma correcta es asignar primero y luego comparar por igualdad:

```
if ( (fp=fopen("programa1.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
```

Asi de simple.

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón, no me había percatado que había agregado un "=" de más. Gracias por la observación.